# Is it possible to slow down Tracker refresh on Meteor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, reactive-programming

I have an app that has a lot of data subscribed but I don’t really need it to be loaded in realtime. Can it be possible to make Tracker refresh data slower, say 5 seconds? I’m developing with React and using withTracker(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can it be possible to make Tracker refresh data slower, say 5 seconds?

The Tracker runs if reactive data changes, so every change in the data that is held inside a Tracker (ReactiveVar, ReactiveDict, Subscription) is causing a re-run.

> ... lot of data subscribed but I don’t really need it to be loaded in realtime.

Then you should definitely remove the subscription and get your data via a [Meteor method](https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-methods).

The publication sends data to the subscriber immediately if the collection updates. If you don't rely on this feature it is basically a waste of server and network resources and if your application will reach a higher level of users, resources will become a big issue.

With a Method you will have some overhead of data if you call it some times in a row, since the data is sent from the collection again (while publications only send deltas) but you are also able to control this behavior much better.

Note, that you loose the reactivity by default but you can put the received data either into a ReactiveVar / ReactiveDict or create a local client-only `Mongo.Collection`.

If you want to keep the benefits of using a Mongo.Collection you just need to insert the received docs in a new local collection:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo'

const LocalCollection = new Mongo.Collection('myLocalData') // should have an own unique name or null
```

and then call your Method inside your React component (but not the `render` method):

```
// call a Meteor.method, pass some arguments, if required
// and parse the resulting documents array.
Meteor.call('getMyDataFromMethod', {foo:'bar'}, (err, documents) => {
  if (err) {
    // handle err
  } else {
    documents.forEach(doc => {
      // update existing docs if present
      // or insert as new into local collection
      if (LocalCollection.findOne(doc._id)) {
        LocalCollection.update(doc._id, { $set: doc })
      } else {
        LocalCollection.insert(doc)
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Since your docs will already contain an `_id` they will preserve the `_id` when inserting in the local collection.

Note that your server method needs to return the fetched documents using `find(...).fetch()` instead of a cursor.

After adding to the local collection you can use it as you already do in your code.

Comment: I know Meteor methods but I would like to keep the cursors.

Comment: In my last line I wrote, that you can also put the received data from your methods into a client-side only Mongo.Collection. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! That make sense! Let me try.

Comment: Did it solve your issue or is there anything still not working?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't fully tried this solution yet. I suddenly have another task to work on. I will let you know once I have solved this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to delay reactivity in meteor,

There might be couple of ways I can solve it

1) just like @jankapunkt said you can use Meteor.methods to pull the data and then you can call the same method for every 5/10 seconds using `Meteor.setInterval` and update the data

2) If you want to use pub/sub then you can subscribe to the data and once subscription is ready then set the data in `reactiveDict` or `reactivieVar` variable and after every 5/10 seconds use update this variable with collection data and use this variable to show data in ui

sample code for second option in blaze, you can use `setState` in react instead of `reactiveDict`

```
import { Template } from "meteor/templating";
import { ReactiveDict } from "meteor/reactive-dict";

Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function() {
  const t = this;
  t.dataDict = new ReactiveDict();
  t.dataDict.set('users', []);
  t.subscribe('my.publication');
})

Template.myTemplate.hlepers(function() {
  users() {
    const t = Template.instance();
    return t.dataDict.get('users') || [];
  }
})

const startInterval = (t) => {
  t.interval = Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    const res = myCollection.find({}).fetch();
    t.dataDict.set('users', res);
  }, 5000);
};

Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {
  const t = this;

  t.autorun(function() {
    if (t.subscriptionsReady()) {
      const res = myCollection.find({}).fetch();
      t.dataDict.set('users', res);
      startInterval()
    }
  })
});

Template.myTemplate.onDestroyed(function() {
  const t = this;
  // clears interval
  Meteor.clearInterval(t.interval);
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it quite similar to the standard way? I'm using `withTracker()` and once there is new data, it will pass the new props to the component and I can update the state with `componentDidUpdate`. I like this approach as I can keep the collection cursors in the components. However, when there are a lot of data being subscribed, the web browser uses a lot of CPU time. I realize that it doesn't have to be so real time. Maybe in every 5 seconds, all data will be changed.